# Computer Restart : it shutdown but it never power up

Tags: boot, power-supply, hardware-failure, power

I am seeing an used desktop computer with MSI motherboard and runs Windows XP,

the problem is when i restart the computer using Windows >> shutdowns >> Restart, the computer shutdown but never power up, even if i press the power button again it doesn't power up until i switch the power supply off then switch it on again, then i can start the computer using the power button, What could cause this problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Try swapping the power supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go into the system's BIOS setup and load defaults, see if that helps. Then perhaps try a known good power supply if the BIOS reset doesnt work to start the troubleshooting process and go from there based on what you find with those attempts.

Comment: This is good advice; normally in situations like this, the computer is failing to recover from a power loss state; be it S3, or whatever else.  if the computer doesn't turn back on after a normal power loss, for example, that would also explain it.  Recovering BIOS to defaults is a good way to ensure that it's not a setting related issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone, but could it be due to a problem in the Motherboard?

Comment: The bios is a motherboard problem. Yes it could also be something else with the motherboard as well. It could also be the PSU.